# alfresco 4.2.e not working on osx mavericks + Java 7

Tags: java, alfresco, cmis

Alfresco 4.2.e not working on osx mavericks + Java 7

I can't login into share. I got the following message: 'Your authentication details have not been recognized or Alfresco may not be available at this time.'

> 2014-02-17 20:40:41,593  ERROR [repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker] [localhost-startStop-1] CONTENT INTEGRITY ERROR: System content not found in content store.
>   2014-02-17 20:40:41,593  ERROR [repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker] [localhost-startStop-1] Ensure that the 'dir.root' property is pointing to the correct data location.
>   2014-02-17 20:40:41,597  ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] [localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
>    org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 01170001 Ensure that the 'dir.root' property is pointing to the correct data location.

and

> 20:51:30,537 WARN  [org.alfresco.wcm.client.util.impl.GuestSessionFactoryImpl] WQS unable to connect to repository: Not Found
>   20:51:44,578 WARN  [org.alfresco.wcm.client.util.impl.GuestSessionFactoryImpl] WQS unable to connect to repository: Not Found
>   2014-02-17 20:51:45,030  ERROR [solr.tracker.CoreTracker] [SolrTrackerScheduler_Worker-2] Tracking failed
>    org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 01170085 GetModelsDiff return status is 404

adding machine name into /etc/hosts do not fix the problem.
Any idea on how to install alfresco on osx mavericks + Java 7

Thanks

Comment: what's your problem in more detail? Any logs/errors?

Comment: What `dir.root` did you give in your alfresco-global properties file, and are you sure it's correct?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the value of the dir.root property in your tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties file, is pointing to the correct location of your content store.

Comment: Any chance you can post the full catalina.out, to see if there are previous errors logged?

Comment: catalina.out file is too big

Comment: just drop the file in dropbox or even Alfresco Cloud & publish the public link here. Catalina.out for a fresh tomcat start should be too large for such services

Comment: In addition, verify that you're not using a new alf_data directory, and an existing, or previously installed alfresco database/schema. This scenario can trigger an integrity violation.

Comment: I deleted the alfresco database from postgres and uninstalled alfresco and reinstalled everything. Problem not solved ;(